# How to connect to mySQL db with UWP

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

I'm Creating an UWP application and trying to set up a db connection with an MYsql local db with a connection string 
I just wanna play around with some db entries on UWP since I used .edmx files when working with windows forms but can't find something similar with UWP

I've added using System.Data.SqlClient; but it still doesn't find the SqlConnection namespace

```
    string connectionString)
       {
           using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                      connectionString))
           {
               SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
               command.Connection.Open();
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
       }
```

For now i just want to connect to the db before trying to add queries 
I've also seen some Youtube vids saying to install a SDK but it contained C++ even though the title said C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a MySQL database, you need to make your project's target version is 16299 or higher and the min version is 16299.

Then, you need to install the nuget package [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/8.0.16)

After that, you could follow the [Use a MySQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/mysql-databases#test-your-connection-using-sample-code) document to test your connection.